# How to allow users to Login to my web application using their google account in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-openid

I am developing a website, in that i want to implement this feature so when ever the user login to their google account i want to get their profile and i want to store it in my database.

i here that it could be done by OAuth. Can any one have best example of this situation please post here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) project? The download includes sample projects for MVC and WebForms.